# groupby and sum the values based on non-duplicated value in another column

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, jupyter-notebook, duplicates

I'm using jupyter notebook and pandas.
I have a dataframe like this:

```
article_id   user_id  Repetition
123           1234       1
123           1234       1
12            1234       0
15            1234       0
567           4899       1
567           4899       1
567           4899       1
909           4899       1
909           4899       1
202           4899       0
```

I want to sum up the values from 'Repetition' column group by 'user_id', however, each 'user_id' will only sum up the values for the unique 'id' column. (output value for the same 'user_id' will be the same)

so the desired output would be:

```
article_id   user_id  Repetition   value
123           1234       1          1
123           1234       1          1
12            1234       0          1
15            1234       0          1
567           4899       1          2
567           4899       1          2
567           4899       1          2
909           4899       1          2
909           4899       1          2
202           4899       0          2
```

The meaning for this output value is: how many articles of a certain user is labelled as 'repetition'.

Any ideas on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: ``df['value'] = df.groupby('user_id').ngroup() + 1`` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
m = df.groupby(['user_id','article_id']).max().sum(level=0)['Repetition']
df['value'] = df['user_id'].map(m)
df
```

Output:

```
   article_id  user_id  Repetition  value
0         123     1234           1      1
1         123     1234           1      1
2          12     1234           0      1
3          15     1234           0      1
4         567     4899           1      2
5         567     4899           1      2
6         567     4899           1      2
7         909     4899           1      2
8         909     4899           1      2
9         202     4899           0      2
```